Software for closest vector problem in $F_2$
I need to solve exactly the closest vector problem over the field $F_2$ with 2 elements, and I am looking for a software that can do better than my brute-force code in C.
Specifically, I have a list of 200 vectors $v_i$ of dimension 1024. I have a target vector t.
I want to know what is the minimum Hamming distance between $t$ and a linear combination over $F_2$ of the $v_i$.  Is there a software that I could solve this?
The vectors come from a combinatorial problem so I would assume they are as nasty as they get; we can't count on any specific structure to exploit.
[Edit] (from a comment) It's maximum likelihood decoding for Reed-Muller codes with certain parameters (degree 3, 10 vars, field $\Bbb{F}_2)$, for a certain word. JL [/Edit]

Can you say more about the combinatorial problem? If you think there is a solution, then may be those aren't as nasty as they get? Why would you think there would be a solution in the first place? There are somewhat general methods better than brute force (such as trying to optimize a trellis representation for this code), but there is no reason to think they would bring the complexity down considerable. Like, if your search space goes from $2^{200}$ down to $2^{170}$ or even $2^{100}$ you aren't really better off.

It's maximum likelihood decoding for Reed-Muller codes with certain parameters (degree 3, 10 vars, field F_2), for a certain word.  Maybe there's something better for this case?  My "200" isn't a definite number, I am happy with anything that pushes me even a little beyond my brute-force search (as long as it's not terribly hard for me to code).

That changes the game quite a bit. Undoubtedly you know that there is a well-known majority logic decoding algorithm that works for Reed-Muller codes, provided that we are within error-correction capability of the code (so fails, if the input is not close enough to a codeword). Beyond that, I'm not fully up to speed. There is a complete decoding algorithm (works for all inputs) due to Seroussi & Lempel that works when the degree is exactly the number of variables minus three.

(cont'd) The recursive structure of Reed-Muller codes also gives an ok trellis representation. I'm not experienced enough with those to say, how much that would cut down the complexity. May be @DilipSarwate recalls a good reference? I try and describe the basic idea of the trellis representation here. My example code there is also a Reed-Muller code, albeit a small one (four variables, degree two).

What you have is a $[1024,200]$ linear code and you wish to decode the received word $t$ into the nearest codeword. This is called maximum-likelihood decoding, and is known to be intractable. See the paper "On the inherent intractability of certain coding problems" by Berlekamp, McEliece, and van Tilborg in the IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, 1978 which is behind IEEE's paywall but free copies can be found on the Internet.

Yes, but the question is whether I can solve it in practice on those parameters, just like Sat is believed intractable but people still solve it on various instances.  There has to be some approach that's better than brute-force search, and hopefully it's in some math software out there.  Thanks.

The improvements to the general result Dilip gave you only apply to those instances, where the given 200 vectors, or rather their span, has some special structure. With more or less random set of vectors? No hope, I think.
